# Ktor client closes before response

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to create an http client with ktor. Using the [code found in the tutorial](https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html#create-client), I have this block,

```
suspend fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    val response: HttpResponse = client.get("https://ktor.io/")
    println(response.status)
    client.close()
}
```

but unmodified from the tutorial, I'm getting this error,

```
2023-07-10 11:45:24.674 [main]  TRACE io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpPlainText - Adding Accept-Charset=UTF-8 to https://ktor.io/
2023-07-10 11:45:25.469 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-6]  TRACE i.k.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator - Processing exception kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedReceiveChannelException: Channel was closed for request https://ktor.io/
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedReceiveChannelException: Channel was closed
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.getReceiveException(BufferedChannel.kt:1729)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.resumeWaiterOnClosedChannel(BufferedChannel.kt:2171)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.resumeReceiverOnClosedChannel(BufferedChannel.kt:2160)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.cancelSuspendedReceiveRequests(BufferedChannel.kt:2153)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.completeClose(BufferedChannel.kt:1930)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.isClosed(BufferedChannel.kt:2209)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.isClosedForSend0(BufferedChannel.kt:2184)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.isClosedForSend(BufferedChannel.kt:2181)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.completeCloseOrCancel(BufferedChannel.kt:1902)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.closeOrCancelImpl(BufferedChannel.kt:1795)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BufferedChannel.close(BufferedChannel.kt:1754)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ChannelCoroutine.close(ChannelCoroutine.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.SendChannel$DefaultImpls.close$default(Channel.kt:98)
    at io.ktor.network.tls.TLSClientHandshake$input$1.invokeSuspend(TLSClientHandshake.kt:91)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:100)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried running in different contexts, changing the http verb, changing the url, adding sleep delays to ensure the call is being completed, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in this instance, the underlying cause of this error was a **proxy issue**. When I disabled my corporate VPN the request was able to complete successfully.

If you're encountering something similar, test if that works, then if it does you can add proxy configuration to the ktor client like so,

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
            engine {
                proxy = ProxyBuilder.http("some_url_your_company_gives_you")
            }
        }
```

For other client engines see the [ktor documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/proxy.html)